# Sorting and hashing a large number of Java strings

Tags: java, sorting, hash

I have an application which stores values of a certain kind of object (say, of type `MyClass`) into a number of different `Map<String, MyClass>` maps.

The application needs to

- Get the object references from the different maps to a single collection (union)
- Sort the single collection (to apply order)
- Calculate the difference between successive collections (for detecting changes)
- Produce a single hash value from all the objects of each collection

The order of the objects in the (unified) collection is important.

To achieve sorting, the objects (map values) are placed, using `addAll()`, in an `ArrayList` and sorted via `Collections.sort()`. The order is defined in `MyClass`, which implements the `Comparator` interface by comparing some string field (say, `myField`) it encapsulates.

After sorting is completed, a unique signature from all the objects is produced. This signature needs to be the same for objects that have the same value of `myField`, which is currently done via string concatenation (using `toLowerCase()` and a `StringBuilder`) and then hashing the resulting string, which can be several thousand characters long.

Is there any more efficient way of doing (any or all of) the above (copying, sorting, comparing and hashing)?

Comment: How about hashing together the hashes of the strings, rather than concatenating into a giant string and taking the hash of that?

Comment: i don't understand the question.  what do the maps have to do with anything?  is the string in the map based on the hash?  why is it a map from string to myclass and not to a list of myclass instances?  when you say "This signature needs to be the same for objects that have the same value of myField" what do you mean?  that the hash depends only on myField?  if it needs to be the same for all of them, why are you combining the hashes?  your entire description is a jumbled mess that makes no sense :o(

Comment: Yes, the wording does seem a bit long-winded. Unless I'm missing something, I think they're basically asking "how do you take a hash of some data to guarantee unique hash codes for each piece of data".

Comment: well sorting seems to be part of the question that no-one is addressing....

Comment: Yup, the creation of a new collection to hold all the references, sorting and then hashing are equally important parts of the algorithm.

Comment: that's a little clearer but still doesn't clarify "This signature needs to be the same for objects that have the same value of myField" (see q above).

Comment: also, why is the sorting needed?  it seems completely arbitrary here.  is it just because you think that will affect the hash?  if so, not sorting and using a hash that is order-independent would save a lot f time...

Comment: If myField for 2 different objects is the same, the 2 objects are considered to be "equivalent", i.e. they should have the same signature, hence the hashing is done on myField. The sorting is needed because the "difference" of successive object collections also needs to be calculated. A lot of processing overall, which is why I am asking for ideas! :-)

Comment: i still don't see why you need sorting.  why don't you put the *actual* requirements (like differences) in your question rathe rthan your confused ideas about what a solution might be?

Comment: OK, so as I understand it, the thing is that you don't want the hash code to depend on the order in which items where added to the list, just on the actual elements. So you could experiment with *keeping* the list sorted, e.g. by using a skip list. Whether it´s worth doing something else really depends on your data, I think -- e.g. I could imagine storing a (non-resizable) hash set of hash codes of fields, if that makes any sense, and combining them at the last minute. This would give you a *determined* order, but not sorted, which is what you require if I understand.

Comment: @Andrew The order of the objects in the unified collection is important. The answers given are all along my description so apparently I am not so confused as you imply, but clarifications always help, so I edited the original post to make things easier. :-)

Comment: @Neil The hash code does depend on the order. My main concern is performance, because there is a lot of processing to be done.

Comment: Well, the hash function will automatically be ordering-sensitive. You don't need to specifically re-order the elements *just* for the hash code.

Comment: @Neil You are right of course for the hashing part, but ordering (sorting) is necessary for comparing the two collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a unique signature, then you (at least conceptually) need to:

- concatenate the relevant data into a string or buffer;
- use a strong hash function to take a hash of that data.

I say "conceptually", because you can potentially calculate the hash on the fly without actually copying all of the data into a buffer: that depends on how convenient this is to do for your particular application.

32-bit hash codes as standardly used in Java are generally too weak to give you unique codes.

I would recommend that you at the very least use a 64-bit hash function (I have an example [implementation of a 64-bit hash function](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/strong_hash_code_implementation.shtml) in one of my articles that may be of help). To give more of a guarantee of uniqueness, a stronger hash function such as MD5 would be more ideal, but just has the slight inconvenience that the resulting hash codes are too wide to store in a primitive. (That's the trade-off you need to make: a 64 strong hash is generally good for guaranteeing uniqueness to all intents and purposes among a few million objects; MD5 gives you a much much stronger guarantee at the expense of wider hash codes.)

P.S. I gave [this answer](http://www.forum.javamex.com/index.php?p=/discussion/5/how-to-start-with-hash-function) the other day to a similar question which may also be of help.

Comment: For speed purposes, would you rather go for MD5 or SHA?

Comment: For the purposes you mention, I think SHA is overkill and I'd use MD5, which is about twice as fast. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/hash_functions_algorithms.shtml

Comment: Of course, if you actually need the hashes to be SECURE (i.e. that given a particular hash, the corresponding data cannot be deduced, and there are enough possible combinations to make this intractable by trial and error), then that's a different matter, as MD5 is no longer actually considered *secure*. (But it's still a strong, relatively fast hash function suitable for the purposes you mention where security isn't strictly speaking required.)

Comment: Security is not an issue, since these are internal and local calculations. If I use a simple calculation like the one suggested by Bohemian (multiplying by 64 or higher instead of 32), would it work? The number of calculations is huge, so I am trying to squeeze every bit of performance.

Comment: Because you want to use hashes as unique identifiers, the higher the quality of the hash, the better. I wouldn't a priori recommend simply multiplying. If you must use a simple method like that, pick a large, prime number (or odd near-prime number) as the multiplier. NEVER NEVER NEVER pick a power of 2 as the multiplier. If you use a simple hash code, then I would test it: run a simulation by generating several million instances of random typical data and checking you don't get collisions.

Comment: P.S. to generate your millions of instances of random data, use a high-quality random number generator such as SecureRandom (never use java.util.Random for this -- it is low period & quality and will give you false positive collisions).

Comment: Thanks very much for all the comments. How would you go about creating the overall hash value? That is, would you first concatenate all strings and then run the MD5 method? If not, how would you combine the current result with the next string, so that the next hash value is produced?

Comment: You can: (a) just re-hash the entire list of values each time an item is added-- probably the simplest, least error-prone method; or (b) always calculate the hashes cyclically, so for each field added to the list, calculate the new hash as hash(H X), where H is previous hash value and X is the value of the field.

Comment: Whenever a hash is calculated, the data is padded. So its trickier (though not impossible) to "update" an existing hash value with some new data-- for cases where you wanted to calculate the whole hash in one go, if you don't calculate it "hash by hash" as in (b), you would need to manually calculate what the padding bytes would have been had you calculated "hash by hash". I think I'll leave that as an 'exercise to the reader' if you really decided to do it that way-- I personally wouldn't bother.

Comment: But it is an interesting security flaw of MD5 and other "secure" hash functions that they do in principle allow you to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a better way. Simply hash the hashes:

```
List<String> strings;

int hash = 0;
for (String string : strings)
    hash += hash * 31 + string.hashCode();
```

This will use virtually no memory, be remarkably fast, and will produce a hash code equal in strength to your StringBuilder approach.

Comment: Though "equal in strength" is not very strong, of course. If the poster genuinely wants a "unique signature", then something stronger will be needed.

Comment: I need uniqueness across several million (or more) values and, of course, the highest possible speed.

Comment: 32-bit hash codes won't give you that level of guarantee. After just a few thousand hashes, the chances of getting a collision are non-negligible. 32-bit hashes are generally designed to be used in cases where they will not be used as a unique identifier, but simply to 'whittle down the choices' before an actual comparison of the data, as in the Java HashMap implementation.

Comment: @NeilCoffey Do you have any evidence for your statement that "something stronger will be needed"? Because I think it's a fine solution. Firstly, a "genuinely unique" `int` hash code is **impossible** for a string "several thousand characters long". Actually, it's going to be impossible for any string longer than 2 chars (2 x 16 bit char = 32 bits)!

Comment: The evidence is simple statistics: with the highest quality 32-bit hash code possible, you will expect a collision after approx 2^16 hashes, (with non-negligible probability a few orders of magnitude below that). With a 64-bit hash code, that figure becomes 2^32, etc...

Comment: Whilst it's literally impossible for every possible piece of data to have a unique hash code, that's not the point. The point is that you reach a hash code width where, unless you deliberately look for collisions, it becomes so improbable that you'll happen upon a collision by chance from some random set of data that you may as well assume they're unique. But such a hash code width is wider than 32 bits. MD5 (which is 128 bits wide) gives you such a guarantee in pretty much all practical situations.

Comment: P.S. I don't know if this helps to clarify things a bit more http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_codes_advanced_statistics.shtml

Answer (score 1):

assuming that what you really want is just a combined hash that describes the collection in a unique way (so internal ordering is unimportant) and which depends only on myField, I would suggest:

```
long hash = 0
for map in maps:
    for key in keys:
        if key in map:
            hash = hash + 64bithash(map[key].myfield)
```

where the additions are all effectively module 2^64.  this will give you a hash for the entire collection that is likely large enough to be unique (64 bits), doesn't depend on ordering (2+3 = 3+2), and doesn't require sorting or storing in additional structures (so will be fast).

**warning** this assumes that order is unimportant.  it may be that your ordering uses something otehr than myfield so that the effective hash depends on both myfield *and* the information used in ordering.  in that case the above will not function equally (but could be made to do so by including the information used for ordering in the has).

Comment: The order is important, hence the sorting. But obviously your algorithm can be used on the key set of the sorted list. Thanks!